# CSS automatically fitting multiple divs to span to the size of a page?

Tags: css

so I need multiple lined divs to span across my page and then do the same thing when another div is added. But I'm not sure how I can achieve this. an example of this is:

[ div 1][ div 2][ div 3][ div 4][ div 5]

And then when another div is added it won't stack below, but decrease the size of the divs to fit into the space.

Comment: If you have the freedom to target HTML5 only, then this is the most beautiful way to do it: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `display: table-cell`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/2X73J/

The browser support is excellent: http://caniuse.com/css-table

```
<div class="multiContainer">
    <div>div 1</div>
    ..
</div>

.multiContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background: #ccc
}
.multiContainer > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed #f0f
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.Someclass div{
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    }
<div class="Someclass">
<div>div 1</div><div>div 2</div><div>div 3</div><div>div 4</div>
</div>
```